# Gradle Hibernate Configuration Requires Mapped Classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, gradle

I'm using Gradle to manage my dependencies for Hibernate (I was previously using Maven), but I've encountered something strange. When I try to save a trivial instance of an annotated class to the database I wind up getting a `MappingException` saying said class is not mapped. This situation is somewhat unique because of the way I've been storing the instances. Assume that the situation is this: I have a properly annotated hibernate class that will be saved using the `Session` from an `EntityManager` using `saveOrUpdate()`. I have a persistance.xml, but no hibernate configuration files. I'm relying on the `EntityManager`s auto detection of mapped classes to feed it to the `Session` so it can be recognized as properly annotated. I'm using Hibernate 4.3.8. The code worked before the switch. All method calls take place in a transactional context and the transaction is committed and the session flushed.

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.gmail.sarah.project.Rank
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.8.Final"
compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35"
```

EDIT (A test case also has the same problem):
Main Class:

```
package com.gmail.physicistsarah.gradletestproject.core;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class Init {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test_Project");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    session.saveOrUpdate(new Person("Carl", "Gauss"));
    session.saveOrUpdate(new Person("Benoit", "Mandelbrot"));
    transaction.commit();
    factory.close();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public static class Person {

    @Column(name = "First_Name", nullable = false)
    private final String firstName;
    @Column(name = "Last_Name", nullable = false)
    private final String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

}
Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Test_Project" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_project_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
mainClassName = "com.gmail.physicistsarah.gradletestproject.core.Init"
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
ext.mainClass = 'com.gmail.physicistsarah.gradletestproject.core.Init'
}
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
classifier = 'sources'
from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
classifier = 'javadoc'
from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
archives sourcesJar
archives javadocJar
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
// You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
// Read more about repositories here:
//   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
// TODO: Add dependencies here ...
// You can read more about how to add dependency here:
//   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.8.Final"
compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35"
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}
```

Exception:

```
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.gmail.physicistsarah.gradletestproject.core.Init$Person
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1096)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1443)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:242)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:671)
at com.gmail.physicistsarah.gradletestproject.core.Init.main(Init.java:23)
```

The persistence.xml (and META-INF package) are in the resources/main folder.

Comment: We can't help without seeing the code, the complete stack trace of the exception and the configuration. Note that the file is supposed to be called persistence.xml, not persistance.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your code:

1. Entities may not be nested classes
2. Entities must have a no-arg constructor
3. Entities fields may not be final
4. Entities must have an attribute annotated with `@Id`
5. Entities must be listed in the persistence.xml file:

   ```
   <class>com.foo.bar.EntityClassName</class>
   ```

Comment: Wow, I was trying to post this way too fast, I didn't even notice that I had no ID in the example class or that it was nested. As far as I know, 2) and 3) are optional provided suitable JVMs. After listing the classes in the `persistence.xml` (and editing the code) everything was fine. Thanks.